# Transforming the quadratic form $x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + x_3x_1$ to its normal form.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to transform $x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + x_3x_1$ to its normal form described by the inertia theorem. How can I find the transformation? I am allowed to complete squares and perform rotations to find the linear change of coordinates. I know how to do a rotation for quadratic forms over $\mathbb{R}^2$ but not $\mathbb{R}^3$. How would I go about manipulating this expression?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix of the quadratic form for the given basis $x_1, x_2, x_3$ is
$$
A = \frac 12\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
For simplicity, I will diagonalize $2A$ first. Eigenvalues of $2A$ can be found by solving
\begin{align}
\lambda^3 - 3 \lambda - 2 & = 0 \\
(\lambda + 1)^2(\lambda - 2) & = 0.
\end{align}
For $\lambda = -1$, the corresponding eigenvector must satisfy
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2\\
u_3
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-u_1\\
-u_2\\
-u_3
\end{pmatrix} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{aligned}
u_1 + u_2 + u_3 = 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
We can pick two arbitrary independent orthogonal solutions. I will pick
$$
u = \begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt 6 \\
1/\sqrt 6 \\
-2/\sqrt 6
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{ and } \quad
v = \begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt 2 \\
-1/\sqrt 2 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
For $\lambda = 2$, we solve for $w$ from
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
w_1\\
w_2\\
w_3\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
2w_1\\
2w_2\\
2w_3
\end{pmatrix} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{aligned}
-2w_1 + w_2 + w_3 & = 0\\
w_1 - 2w_2 + w_3 & = 0\\
\end{aligned}.
$$
It is easy to see that $w = \begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt 3\\1/\sqrt 3\\1/\sqrt 3\end{pmatrix}$ is a solution.
Therefore,
$$
2A = \begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt 6 & 1/\sqrt 2 & 1/\sqrt 3\\
1/\sqrt 6 & -1/\sqrt 2 & 1/\sqrt 3\\
-2/\sqrt 6 & 0 & 1/\sqrt 3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt 6 & 1/\sqrt 2 & 1/\sqrt 3\\
1/\sqrt 6 & -1/\sqrt 2 & 1/\sqrt 3\\
-2/\sqrt 6 & 0 & 1/\sqrt 3
\end{pmatrix}^T.
$$
The factor $2$ (or its reciprocal) can be pushed to the middle matrix of eigenvalues. This does not change the eigenvectors. The matrix of eigenvectors is the change of coordinates that you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$f = \begin{pmatrix}
x, y, z\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0, 1, 0\\
0, 0, 1\\
1, 0, 0\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z\\
\end{pmatrix}$

And you need to represent the matrix A in the form: $S^TDS$, where  conjugate transpose of S: $S^* = S^{-1}$. So the matrix S gives you necessary mapping to get the normal form. And the coefficients of D gives you coefficients of the normal form.

P.S. There will be complex roots.